# What tools help managing the architecture?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, architecture

What are those tools that help *managing* the architecture especially in the Visual Studio / TFS era?

I don't really think for those tools that help expressing *what* the architecture should be; I rather mean those **tools or features of VS/TFS** that help the code **to stay aligned with the architecture**.

**For example,** allowing changing the public interfaces or dependencies of a component or a layer only to architects.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio can help you create and maintain a layered architecture: [Create layer diagrams from your code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465141.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: How does this anwer the question??

Comment: It seems that layer diagrams together with 1) verification step as part of the check-in process and 2) allowing edits of layer diagram files in TFVC only to architects would do exactly what we need. What is your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the work item and model link in VS to improving your architecture.

> **Improve architecture with modeling tools**
>
> Visual Studio provides developers and architects modeling capabilities
>   to help them build even the most complex software. In this video,
>   you’ll learn how our modeling tools can help improve and maintain your
>   software architecture as part of your development lifecycle
>
> Source Link:https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/architecture-and-modeling-vs.aspx

Comment: Same as above: It seems that layer diagrams together with 1) verification step as part of the check-in process and 2) allowing edits of layer diagram files in TFVC only to architects would do exactly what we need. What is your opinion?